# MySQL update with if evaluation in same table

Tags: mysql, sql-update, case

I need some help.

I got this table:

```
---------
ID | N1 |
---------
a    100
b    150
c    90
d    240
--------
```

Given 2 IDs (for example a,b) I need to do that:

```
If (a.n1 > b.n1) 
        
       a.n1 = b.n1
    
else 
        b.n1=a.n1;
```

How can I do it on MySQL?

Comment: Do what exactly, Update table or select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting to update a table in this manner you can use a Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE TABLE T (ID VARCHAR(5), N1 INT);
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE check_vals (IN a VARCHAR(5), IN b VARCHAR(5)) BEGIN 
SET @a = (SELECT N1 FROM T WHERE ID = a); 
SET @b = (SELECT N1 FROM T WHERE ID = b); 
IF @a > @b THEN UPDATE T SET N1 = @b WHERE ID = a; 
ELSE UPDATE T SET N1 = @a WHERE ID = b; 
END IF; 
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then Just use the procedure like this:

```
CALL check_vals('a','b');
SELECT * FROM T;
```

Returns:

```
+----+-----+
| ID | N1  |
+----+-----+
| a  | 100 |
| b  | 100 |
| c  |  90 |
| d  | 240 |
+----+-----+
```

Otherwise, if your goal is to only manipulate the data in a SELECT result, then I would go with P.Salmon's answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;

CREATE TABLE T
(D VARCHAR(1), N1 INT);
INSERT INTO T VALUES
('a'  ,  100),
('b'  ,  150),
('c'  ,  90),
('d'  ,  240);


SELECT T.D,(SELECT MAX(N1) MAXNI FROM T WHERE D IN('A','B')) N1
FROM  T WHERE D IN('A','B');

+------+------+
| D    | N1   |
+------+------+
| a    |  150 |
| b    |  150 |
+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a self join:

```
UPDATE tablename t1 
INNER JOIN tablename t2 
ON ('a', 'b') IN ((t1.ID, t2.ID), (t2.ID, t1.ID))
SET t1.N1 = LEAST(t1.N1, t2.N1)
```

Although, the self join will return 2 rows, only 1 will be updated (or none of both `N1`s are equal), because MySql does not actually perform the update if the original value is equal to the new value.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=fec681e719534925087dfb1c78c0cc4c).
Results:

| ID | N1 |
| --- | --- |
| a | 100 |
| b | 100 |
| c | 90 |
| d | 240 |